# python - subtract a field value with an .aggregate(Sum()) result

Tags: python, django

I have 2 fields, total annual leaves and annual leaves taken, 
using `.aggregate(Sum())` I've calculated the of total annual leaves taken for an employee.

but now I want to calculate the remaining leaves available for the user, which is

> total annual leaves - total annual leaves taken

but I'm having trouble doing it because the `annual_taken` is a string and not a float

Its giving me this error :

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'

How can I fix this? Any help is much appreciated

Below is my code :
model.py

```
class LeavesEntitlement(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    type = models.ForeignKey(LeavesType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    days = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
class Leave(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    type = models.ForeignKey(LeavesType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+')
    duration = models.FloatField()
```

View.py

```
def my_leaves_view(request):
    annual = LeavesEntitlement.objects.all().filter(employee=request.user.profile.employee.id, type=1)
    annual_taken = Leave.objects.all().filter(employee=request.user.profile.employee.id, type=1).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
    for annual_field in annual:
        for field in annual_taken:
            annual_available = annual_field.days - field

    context = {'form': form,
               'annual': annual,
               'annual_taken': annual_taken,
               'annual_available': annual_available
           }
    return render(request, 'hrm/my_leaves/my_leaves_content.html', context)
```

HTML

```
<table id="my_entitlement_table" class="display table table-hover table-responsive" width="100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Leave Type</strong></th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Total</strong></th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Taken</strong></th>
            <th class="small text-muted text-uppercase"><strong>Available</strong></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {% for annual_field in annual %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{annual_field.days}}</td>
                    <td>{{annual_taken.duration__sum}}</td>
                    <td>{{annual_available}}</td>
                </tr>
             {% endfor %
         </tbody>
```

Comment: include full traceback in your question

Comment: okay, one moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In field you have a dict, so

with some refactoring (don't need all if use filter, and more readable if once define employee) your code may look:

```
employee = request.user.profile.employee.id
annual = LeavesEntitlement.objects.filter(employee=employee, type=1)
annual_taken = Leave.objects.filter(employee=employee, type=1).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
for annual_line in annual:
    annual_available = annual_line.days - annual_taken.get('duration__sum', 0)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @Bear Brown, it works! Thank you so much for you help! no idea why would someone down vote your answer

Comment: glad to help you) the people so people))

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation sum return a key value pair so you have to get the value from dict.

```
annual_taken = Leave.objects.all()
                    .filter(employee=request.user.profile.employee.id, 
                     type=1).aggregate(Sum('duration'))
```

then

```
sum_taken = annual_taken.get('duration__sum')
```

Also this loop in your code

```
   for field in annual_taken:
        annual_available = annual_field.days - field
```

is wrong. You are trying to iterate over a dict. Removing this loop and using `sum_taken` will work no need to loop